# CakePHP 3: switching between Router scopes

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

I have a simple routing setup to address different languages. The goal is to have the language as a first parameter in the url like `/en/docs` or `/de/docs`. The language definitions are set as `scopes` as show below:

```
$builder = function ($routes)
{
  $routes->connect('/:controller', ['action' => 'index']);
  $routes->connect('/:controller/:action/*', ['action' => 'index']);
};

$languages = ['en', 'de'];
foreach ($languages as $lang) {
  Router::scope('/'.$lang, ['language' => $lang], $builder);
}

Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
  if ($request->param('language')) {
    $params['language'] = $request->param('language');
  }
  else {
    $params['language'] = 'en';
  }
  return $params;
});
```

Each of the scopes is working as expected. Even with some more complex connects and prefixes (I removed them from the code above to make the code more readable).

**The problem is now: how to create a link to switch between the languages (scopes)?**

I tried different urls, but depending on the current url (e.g. `/de/docs`), the language parameter does not have any effect on the created urls:

```
Router::url(['language' => 'en', 'controller' => 'docs']);
// -> /de/docs (expected: /en/docs)
Router::url(['language' => 'de', 'controller' => 'docs']);
// -> /de/docs
```

How to fix the routes to get the expected urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for this behaviour. The function `addUrlFilter` replaced the language parameter when generating the urls and the result was always the current language. An updated version of this function does the job:

```
Router::addUrlFilter(function ($params, $request) {
  if (!isset($params['language'])) {
    $params['language'] = $request->param('language');
  }
  return $params;
});
```

Puuh, one hour of searching and trying...